How to do retry in fabric8 watcher
I have a watcher witch watches a crd. When new action comes and fails I want my watcher to retry the crd action until it is done. I think this can be done in kubernetes oficial client.
val watcher = object : Watcher<Task> {
            override fun eventReceived(action: Action, task: Task) {
                val name = task.metadata.name
                when (action) {
                    Action.ADDED -> {
                            try {
                                // do something can fail
                            } catch (e: Exception) {
                                throw e
                            }
                        }
                    }
                   else -> {
                       
                }
            }

            override fun onClose(exception: WatcherException?) {
                exception?.let {
                    throw exception
                }
            }
        }

I added a line of the code which will fail and I am expecting my watcher to retry.
